# Sum the same value with different condition

Tags: mysql

Ok, the title is cryptic but I don't know how to sintetize it better.

I have a series of expensive similar SELECT SUM queries that must be executed in sequence.

Example:

```
SELECT SUM(t2.Field) 
FROM Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Field FROM Table2
  WHERE [list of where]
) AS t2 ON ti.ExtKey = t2.Key
WHERE t1.TheValue = 'Orange'

SELECT SUM(t2.Field) 
FROM Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Field FROM Table2
  WHERE [list of where]
) AS t2 ON ti.ExtKey = t2.Key
WHERE t1.TheValue = 'Apple'
```

And so on.
I've used the nested inner join because after some test it resulted faster than a plain Join.

The rows selected for Table2 are always the same, or at least the same for session.
There's a way to group all the queries in one to speed up the execution?

I was thinking about using a material view, but this would complicate very much the design and maintenance.

Comment: "I've used the nested inner join because after some test it resulted faster than a plain Join." On an indexed table, this just seems unlikely. But anyway, UNION is your friend

Answer (score 3):

I am no sure about your goal. I have a guess for you:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af66e/2

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af66e/1

```
SELECT 
  SUM(IF(t1.TheValue = 'Orange',t2.Field,0)) as oranges,
  SUM(IF(t1.TheValue = 'Apple',t2.Field,0)) as apples
FROM Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Field, `key` FROM Table2

) AS t2 ON t1.ExtKey = t2.`key`
# GROUP BY t1.extkey uncomment if you need it
```

If you can provide raw data sample and expected result that would help a lot.

Comment: I tried it with a plain SUM(t2.Field) too for additional reference, but returns the same value for all three

Comment: It is absolutely unclear to me this your comment. Provide sample of data and expected result please

Comment: I've tried SUM(IF(t1.TheValue = 'Orange',t2.Field,0)) as oranges,
  SUM(IF(t1.TheValue = 'Apple',t2.Field,0)) as apples, and for additional reference added SUM(t2.Field) to get the total, but all oranges, apples and total return the sum of all the rows. es: 168, 168, 168

Comment: Probably you should set some criteria for `GROUP BY`, but even if there is no `GROUP BY` statement - it works, check my fiddle, and provide yours if you really need help

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `group by`:

```
SELECT t1.TheValue, SUM(t2.Field) 
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN
     (SELECT Field
      FROM Table2
      WHERE [list of where]
     ) t2
     ON t1.ExtKey = t2.Key
GROUP BY t1.theValue;
```

Note that your query doesn't quite make sense, because `t2` doesn't have a column called `key`.  I assume this is an oversight in the question.

If you want to limit it to particular values, then use a `WHERE` clause before the `GROUP BY`:

```
WHERE t1.TheValue IN ('Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear')
```